# Передача данный с одного ViewController на другой

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone, uibutton

Имеется вот такой вот кусок кода. Программа создает 1000 кнопок которые отображены на scrollView. У каждой кнопки есть свой тег, который отображается на ней. Задача сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на любую из кнопок можно было перейти на другой viewController и на нем отображался порядковый номер этой кнопки. Спасибо!

```
@implementation RWTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.mainScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
_mainScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
_mainScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
_mainScroll.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview: _mainScroll];
_mainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 12520);

CGFloat x=0;
CGFloat y=0;


for (int i=0; i < 250; i++) {

    for (int k=0; k< 4; k++) {

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y,80, 50);

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        button.tag = i*4+k;
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", button.tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.mainScroll addSubview: button];
                    x = x+80;
    }
    x = 0;
    y = y+50;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов.

Самый простой - сделать `property` (к примеру `tagtag`), у другого view controller-a. Создать segue для перехода на него. И в методе `buttonPressed` вызывать этот segue по его идентификатору типа такого:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toТвойИД" sender:self];
```

только перед вызовом этого метода нужно в какую-то глобальную переменную записать значение `tag`.

создать метод:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{   
<название viewcontroller-a> *destController  = [segue     destinationViewController];
destController.tagtag = <переменная со значением tag>;
}
```

ну и в `viewDidLoad` другого контроллера обрабатывать `tagtag`

или можно при помощи уведомлений `NSNotification`